# Authentication implementation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, form-authentication

I've been building a ASP.NET site for masses. Being a web form developers I am aware about sessions and its timeout. But they are annoying, as they get expired very often and sliding it won't also help when working on a site which user may want to open for complete day.
I am not sure how stack overflow has implemented it but I understand that it may be using cookies to keep my session alive even when I am not doing any activity on the site. I am following up tutorial on [ASP.NET MVC registration and login form](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/f769698f-fed6-43eb-8e61-d7baaf713819/Login%20and%20Registration%20Form%20in%20ASP%20Net%20MVC#.Vd2k5eOSxkE) which is using:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms loginUrl="~/Home/LogOn"defaultUrl="~/Home/Home"timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I am completely newbie to ASP.NET MVC so I am not even sure what should I have to search on internet to understand **what I have to do to implement login & registration in such a way that user will be remain online for long and at the same time it won't create load on my server**. **Is Form authentication a good choice for website that is for large number of logged in users?**

As per my understanding, form authentication stores data in cookies. Is it true for ASP.NET MVC too? I was expecting .ASPXAUTH cookie for stackoverflow also (Below screen shows the cookies I got from SO)

[image]

**Note**: I am completely newbie in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: token authentication is preferred and easiest imho.  If you create a new MVC app with authentication in visual studio it will show you how to build it.

Comment: Have a look at OWIN Authentication

Comment: @Jonesopolis Can you redirect me to any tutorial related to it? I mean, I have a user table and I can not use any third party (ex: Google, Facebook etc) for login. When I searched on google I found OAuth.. is it the same?

Comment: Take a look at ASP.NET Identity, it should include everything you need. http://www.asp.net/identity